# URL limit in Flask

Tags: python, api, flask, url, routes

I'm trying creating an API that takes a huge text as input using Flask in python.

[image]

When I input a small text it works and I get `response [200]`, However for large text I get `response [404]` as if the route doesn't exist. How can I get over this?

Comment: How long is "long"? Even browsers exhibit some maximum URL length, and any component in between might as well, so it's not advisable to try to use URLs longer than ~1024 characters or so in practice.

Comment: send data in the request body?

Comment: Yes it's definitely more than 1024 characters. "long" as in 300 words approx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url has a *maximum* length limit. I suggest you use the **post** method and pass the text content as the **request body**.
If you need Code, just comment and let me know.

Comment: Yes Please I'd appreciate your help. I tried the post method but apparently I didn't apply it correctly. Thank you in advance.